# System.XmlException: start tag unexpected character =

Tags: apex, xml, httpcalloutmock, xmlparsing

This is the full error:

```
System.XmlException: start tag unexpected character = (position: END_TAG seen ...<source> Bicycling</source><media:contenturl=... @1:688)
```

So from my understanding, this is not valid XML. I was having an issue with the session body and had to make the following change:

```
<rss xmlns:media="http:..." and had to add <rss\txlmns:media=\"https:..."
```

Now, I am not sure how to go about this with the = sign.

```
@isTest
    global class getRSSFeedMockCallout implements HttpCalloutMock 
{

  global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
  {
      String sessionBody = '<rss\txmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\"version=\"2.0\">' +
      '<channel>'+
        '<item>'+
          '<title>Draymond Green Is a SoulCycle Devotee - Bicycling</title>'+
          '<link>https://www.bicycling.com/news/a27024393/draymond-green-soulcycle/</link>'+
          '<pubDate>Wed, 03 Apr 2019 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>'+
          '<description><a href=\"https://www.bicycling.com/news/a27024393/draymond-green-soulcycle/\"target=\"_blank\">Draymond Green Is a SoulCycle Devotee</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">Bicycling</font><p>If you take SoulCycle classes in the Bay Area, and you notice one extremely tall guy in the room, you may be looking at Golden State Warriors star Draymond ...</p></description>'+
          '<source>Bicycling</source>'+
          '<media:contenturl=\"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/QvLCgDJMIqLENGFBUt1CCoUPO1XB6gJkGFPV5FuM0QKfyaG8WdhuHGtfcVaTzNzPAYyHo-arnqUBkWkZ8s7-p7WBUbKlfJ4xr0hl8hltQWsBCG0yDDh13Ul5qKrZgLvjQitRecmu=-w150-h150-c\"medium=\"image\"width=\"150\"height=\"150\"/>'+
        '</item>'+
      '</channel>'+
    '</rss>';


      HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
      res.setBody( sessionBody );
      res.setStatusCode(200);
      return res;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things wrong with the xml.

1) In Apex, the string starts and end with single quotes `'` , thus you don't need to escape `"`

2) You cannot use `&` in [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625602/how-to-display-nbsp-in-xml-output), it makes XML invalid, you have to escape it. `&nbsp;` will become `&amp;nbsp;`

3) There is no tag as `media:contenturl` in [rss specification](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss) ,the tag is `media:content` and having `url` as an attribute. Seems like you missed a space in that.

Thus fixing all the above problem and formating the code, the code would be something like

```
String input = '<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">' +
        '<channel>' +
        '<item>' +
        '<title>Draymond Green Is a SoulCycle Devotee - Bicycling</title>' +
        '<link>https://www.bicycling.com/news/a27024393/draymond-green-soulcycle/</link>' +
        '<pubDate>Wed, 03 Apr 2019 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>' +
        '<description>' +
        '<a href="https://www.bicycling.com/news/a27024393/draymond-green-soulcycle/" target="_blank">Draymond Green Is a SoulCycle Devotee &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; </a>' +
        '<font color="#6f6f6f">Bicycling</font>' +
        '<p>If you take SoulCycle classes in the Bay Area, and you notice one extremely tall guy in the room, you may be looking at Golden State Warriors star Draymond ...</p>' +
        '</description>' +
        '<source>Bicycling</source>' +
        '<media:content url ="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/QvLCgDJMIqLENGFBUt1CCoUPO1XB6gJkGFPV5FuM0QKfyaG8WdhuHGtfcVaTzNzPAYyHo-arnqUBkWkZ8s7-p7WBUbKlfJ4xr0hl8hltQWsBCG0yDDh13Ul5qKrZgLvjQitRecmu=-w150-h150-c" medium="image" width="150" height="150"/>' +
        '</item>' +
        '</channel>' +
        '</rss>';


System.debug(input);
```

Comment: You are the man! Works perfectly now.